# Passing function as default value of an optional parameter

Tags: flutter, dart, oop, dart-null-safety

I'm trying to pass a function as default value of an optional parameter, but it gives me the followig error "**The default value of an optional parameter must be constant**"

```
class ElevatedBtn extends StatelessWidget {
  final String text;
  final color, width, height, onTap;
  
  const ElevatedBtn(
    {super.key, required this.text, this.color, this.width, this.height, this.onTap=(){} }
   );
}
```

Comment: You can only use constant values as default values, and function literals aren't considered constants, but top level functions and static functions count as constants, so you can and pass either of those as a default value to onTap. There is a proposal to add constant function literals to the language (https://github.com/dart-lang/language/issues/1048) but it isn't allowed in dart today.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Default value of positional parameters are needed to be `const`.  You can make onTap nullable and call your method on null case like

```dart
class ElevatedBtn extends StatelessWidget {
  final String text;
  final color, width, height;
  final VoidCallback? onTap;

  const ElevatedBtn({
    super.key,
    required this.text,
    this.color,
    this.width,
    this.height,
    this.onTap,
  });

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ElevatedButton(
      onPressed: onTap ?? () {},
      child: Text("btn"),
    );
  }
}
```